# How to avoid timout by NOT using sleep in Ruby watir web page scripting?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
  [5040:6784:0906/150930:FATAL:platform_canvas.cc(70)] SK_CRASH              ] 55%
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Ti
meout::Error)

        from letsmt_rr_filetype_uploader.rb:43:in `block in <main>'
        from letsmt_rr_filetype_uploader.rb:39:in `each'
        from letsmt_rr_filetype_uploader.rb:39:in `<main>'
```

This is an rbuf-fill timout error on file uploading progress. Is there any different method to avoid this by **NOT**using sleep ?

This is the script im using for file upload:

```
puts "Tiek veikta atlasīto failu ielāde..."
progress = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Failu ielāde:", :progress_mark => "|", :format => "%t [%B] %p%%", :total => kolekcija.length)
kolekcija.each do |fails|
    @fails = fails[0]
    @b.div(:id, "pageHeader").link(:text, "Corpora").click
    @b.span(:class => "btnText", :text => "Upload corpus").when_present.click
    @b.text_field(:id, "corp_save_field_title").set("TestAuto #{File.basename(@fails)}") # Name / Title
    @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").frame(:index, 0).file_field(:id, "FileUploadHTML").set(@fails) # File absolute path
    @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").frame(:index, 0).span(:text, "Upload").click
    @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").table(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles").wait_until_present
    @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").select_list(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles_ctl02_ddlChooseType").option(:value, "#{fails[1]}").select
    @b.send_keys :tab
    if @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").select_list(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles_ctl02_ddlChooseLanguage").enabled?
        @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").select_list(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles_ctl02_ddlChooseLanguage").select("English")
        # @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").select_list(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles_ddlChooseLanguage_0").option(:value, "#{@filelang}".select
    end
    @b.send_keys :tab
    @b.span(:class => "btnText", :text => "Save", :index => 1).when_present.click
    @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").table(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles").wait_until_present
    sleep 15
    progress.increment
end
```

Comment: Can you show your code (preferably in a fiddle)?

Comment: Just posted the script code.

Comment: It is not clear which part (ie line) is actually throwing the exception. What is line 43?

Comment: according to notepad ++ its

@b.text_field(:id, "corp_save_field_title").set("TestAuto #{File.basename(@fails)}") # Name / Title

But according to my counting only code lines its:
@b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").table(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles").wait_until_present
 sleep 15

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before and it was caused by elements on the page that were being loaded via ajax where not responding hence causing the page to timeout in the same manner. 
Eventually the only way to fix it was to wrap that particular call in a try catch. in addition to the try catch, try changing your sleep to a wait_until_present on any confirmation that comes up after the file upload. If there isnt one there, it may be worth adding one behind the scenes you can hook in to to confirm the file has completed uploading.